# Finding the sum of multiples of any number less than the specified number. Where is my mistake?

Tags: java, algorithm

[This is my another solution where the output is shown as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgIiF.png)

```
 public class Logic2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            long sum = 0;
            calculation key = new calculation();
            sum = key.sum(3, 1000);
            System.out.print(sum);
        }
   }

class calculation {
    long total = 0;
    public long sum(int num, int limit) { //multples of num less than limit
        int number = Integer.valueOf(limit / num);
        if (limit % num == 0) {
            number -= 1;
        }

        total = (number / 2) * (2 * num + (number - 1) * num);
        return total;
    }
}
```

I wrote this code myself. It seems everything fine but I am not getting the required output. Why is this so?

Comment: Please describe the problem

Comment: What's your required output?

Comment: Can you let us know what is your `required output` and what you get?

Comment: Mind including the output you're seeing?  e.g. Is your mistake that the program doesn't terminate?  That the output is unexpected?  That there's no output?  What output did you expect?  Also, what did you attempt in order to debug?

Comment: For sum(3, 1000), required output is 166833. but by this code, I am getting 166332.

Comment: This problem is about. For examples; multiples of 3 less than 10 is 3, 6. 9. Here we have to show sum of those numbers 3+6+9 .

Comment: Since I am learner, I manually mathematically calculated values and used another method to check output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your math is just slightly wrong. Try breaking it up into smaller parts to confirm you're getting what you're expecting. A working example which returns 166833

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 3, N = 1000;
    System.out.println("Sum of multiples of " + a +
            " up to " + N + " = " +
            calculate_sum(a, N));

}

private static int calculate_sum(int a, int N) {
    // Number of multiples
    int m = N / a;

    // sum of first m natural numbers
    int sum = m * (m + 1) / 2;

    // sum of multiples
    return a * sum;
}
```

If you split your method up the same way, you will see where you've missed the mark slightly.

Comment: Chris Turner
Thanks for your help but Can you please tell me where my maths is wrong in the code? I used this formula: Sn=(n/2)(2a+(n-1)d)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Logic2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            long sum = 0;
            calculation key = new calculation();
            sum = key.sum(3, 1000);
            System.out.print(sum);
        }
   }

class calculation {
    long total = 0;
    public long sum(int num, int limit) { //multples of num less than limit
        int number = Integer.valueOf(limit / num);
        if (limit % num == 0) {
            number -= 1;
        }

       total=((number)*(2*num+(number-1)*num))/2;
//previouslly total = (number / 2) * (2 * num + (number - 1) * num);
        return total;
    }
}
```

I figured out the bug myself. In that, Total if we write (number/2) then it will give integer value due to which I was not getting the required output. Anyways, Thanks everyone for at list viewing my post, I appreciate it. :)